# Make: Is it possible to have dependencies constructed from a pattern match?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The goal here is to dynamically adapt and process `results-0`, `results-1`, ..., `results-n` as `results-*` appear in the makefile's directory and I call make with a cron job.

The `make` I am using is `gnu-make vers. 4.3` installed on a mac via brew.

---

I have written the following MVP which represents my actual problem, and it works.  Note that, in my real problem there isn't a full chain of wild-cards and the essential problem is represented by the area that gets commented out and un-commented:

```
sources:=result-0/foo.txt result-0/bar.txt result-1/foo.txt result-1/bar.txt
results:=result-0.txt result-1.txt

result-%/:
  @-mkdir $@

result-0/%.txt: result-0
  @touch $@

result-1/%.txt: result-1
  @touch $@


#.SECONDEXPANSION:
#result-%.txt: $$(filter $$(basename $$@)/%,$$(sources))
# @echo $^ args of: $@
# @touch $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:
result-0.txt: $$(filter $$(basename $$@)/%,$$(sources))
  @echo $^ args of: $@
  @touch $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:
result-1.txt: $$(filter $$(basename $$@)/%,$$(sources))
  @echo $^ args of: $@
  @touch $@

all: $(results)
```

I build it with the command:

```
mkdir result-0
touch result-0/foo.txt
touch result-0/bar.txt
echo result-0/foo.txt result-0/bar.txt args of: result-0.txt
touch result-0.txt
mkdir result-1
touch result-1/foo.txt
touch result-1/bar.txt
echo result-1/foo.txt result-1/bar.txt args of: result-1.txt
touch result-1.txt
rm result-1
```

Which represents a successful first build.

---

But, when I make the following change to abstract across `result-[0...n]`, the system breaks:

```
sources:=result-0/foo.txt result-0/bar.txt result-1/foo.txt result-1/bar.txt
results:=result-0.txt result-1.txt

result-%/:
  @-mkdir $@

result-0/%.txt: result-0
  @touch $@

result-1/%.txt: result-1
  @touch $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:
result-%.txt: $$(filter $$(basename $$@)/%,$$(sources))
  @echo $^ args of: $@
  @touch $@

all: $(results)
```

The system breaks:

```
$ make all -Bn
mkdir result-0.txt
mkdir result-1.txt
```

---

It has been noted that I could simply make the following change:

```
# instead of 
result-%.txt: $$(filter $$(basename $$@)/%,$$(sources))

# I could write
$(results): $$(filter $$(basename $$@)/%,$$(sources))
```

This is something I am aware of, and it I have zero trouble making this work on my side (I have working code).  This is not the question I am asking.  I am **not** asking **"how do I debug this".**

I **am** asking: **"why isn't the following rule expression populating the pre-requisites in the second expansion?"**

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
results-%:  $$(filter $$(basename $$@)/%,$$(sources))
```

And everything around this question is *not* an effort to *motivate* the question, *but rather* an effort to *demonstrate* the issue.  If there is another way to "make this example work", that is out of scope.

---

Is it possible to do this with make? Is this one of the odd problems you'll see on Mac?

And, again, if the issue right now seems to be `result-0/%.txt` grabbing the pattern match further up the chain, that is not actually what I am dealing with.  I have developed a copy-paste demo with no files, and if I have inadvertently added another reason this pattern expansion might fail, then I've screwed up in my demo of the problem. So if that is the issue, I can re-work this question.

Comment: I don't see any wildcard here. You should be able to combine the two pattern rules with `result-0.txt result-1.txt: result-%.txt:`

Comment: @tripleee the result-0.txt derives from a directory that gets created by a remote source, `result-0/`, and these directories will accumulate arbitrarily.  The idea is to find them all, and with the wild-card, match them all up to their rule.  So, please understand this is a Minimal Verifiable, and not the Maximum Unverifiable Actual

Comment: But if your MVP doesn't contain a wildcard, how can we guess where you are actually using a wildcard? Or do you actually mean a pattern rule?

Comment: @tripleee the wildcard is uncommented: `result-%.txt`.  But I see what you are saying.

Comment: That's a pattern rule, not a wildcard. Wildcards are different, and only expand to existing files. For example, `rule-[01].txt` will expand to `rule-0.txt` if that file exists, and the other one doesn't.

Comment: @tripleee Ah, I see. Well, feel free to adjust the language so that it makes sense.  I understood the '%' to be the wildcard symbol from the docs. Anyhow, I think I can make it work with that mult-match method, but I really thought the second expansion would work here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I **am** asking: **"why isn't the following rule expression populating
> the pre-requisites in the second expansion?"**
>
> ```
> .SECONDEXPANSION:
> results-%:  $$(filter $$(basename $$@)/%,$$(sources))
> ```

Oddly enough, your troublesome makefile works as I think you expected with GNU `make` version 4.0:

```
> make --version
GNU Make 4.0
Built for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
>
> make -Bn
echo  args of: result-0.txt
touch result-0.txt
echo  args of: result-1.txt
touch result-1.txt
```

I checked the release notes for versions 4.1, 4.2, and 4.3, and did not see anything that I recognized as describing this change.  Nevertheless, I think I can explain what is happening in version 4.3.

The first expansion yields this rule:

```
results-%:  $(filter $(basename $@)/%,$(sources))
```

You are expecting `make` to match that to targets such as `results-0`, expand `$@` in the scope of that assignment, and then evaluate the `filter` function.  But what about that `%` among the function arguments?

You are relying on the `%` in the prerequisite list to be relayed literally to `filter`, but when `make` evaluates a pattern rule, it substitutes the matching stem of the target for appearances of `%` in the prerequisite list.  In this case, it looks like `make` is doing that before evaluating the function call, such that the resulting prerequisite list does not match existing or buildable targets.  As a result, the rule is rejected.

This is basically an order-of-execution difference.  If the function call is expanded before the stem substition is performed then the result you wanted is obtained, but if the stem substitution is performed first then your rule does not work as desired.  I do not find this specific detail explicitly documented, but my reading of the general behavior of pattern rules leads me to expect the stem substitution to be performed first (so I judge GNU `make` 4.0 to be buggy in this regard).

In any event, this does not appear to be directly related to the second expansion.  I would expect similar order-of-execution effects to apply in any pattern rule that attempted to use a `%` as a literal character in the prerequisite list.

Comment: Nvm my prior comment; the `%` literal in `filter` was supposed to be a pattern matcher, and `$$(basename $$@)` is supposed to be "`results-n` where `n` is the number matched by `%` on the left hand side -- I'll get back to this when I'm on a computer, but I think you may be right and I might have learned a bug

Comment: Perhaps I can get around it by defining `WildCard=%`, and calling `$$(filter $$(basename $$@)/$$(WildCard), ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve exactly, so I just guess based on what you consider as a successful build. I will create the source files with a simple [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) and, as you tried yourself, use the second expansion to list the dependencies of the results. The following should not be too far from what you want:

```
sources:=result-0/foo.txt result-0/bar.txt result-1/foo.txt result-1/bar.txt
results:=result-0.txt result-1.txt

.PHONY: all
all: $(results)

$(sources): %.txt:
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @touch $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(results): $$(filter $$(basename $$@)/%,$(sources))
    @echo $^ args of: $@
    @touch $@
```

Comment: That's what I ended up going with, but I really expected to be able to avoid defining a variable or pre-calculating the `$(results)` list of files that will result in that execution.

Comment: Then you should consider adding some information to your question. How do you intend to discover the source files? And how do you decide which result files should be generated? In your second attempt they are still explicitly listed. And this is the kind of things we cannot really guess. Is there a kind of pattern or something?

Comment: Basically there is one point of confusion: why does `%` not match on the pattern side (the left side) **And** get used on the pre-requisites side when second expansion is used?   Instead, we have to populate the file names and plop them there on the pattern side.  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: please see my clarifying comments.